# How to return a value from a recursive asynchronous callback?

Tags: javascript, facebook, asynchronous, recursion

I'm using the facebook js sdk, I'm trying to get a list of all groups, the response is pageinated.  So recursion seems like a an obvious solution for this

```js
function handlePaging(response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    if (response.paging.next) {
      return response.data.concat(FB.api(response.paging.next, handlePaging));
    } else {
      return response.data;
    }
  }
}

console.log(FB.api("/me/groups", handlePaging));
```

But because its asynchronous I'm getting undefined returned.  I've had a look at other returning values from asynchronous requests, but none of them were recursive, and the answer was use a callback, which I have.

I'm not even sure if this is even possible.

Comment: Returning values from asynchronous callbacks, as a general rule, doesn't make sense.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, I've just replanned how the script is going to work to get around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to FB.api is asynchronous so it returns immediately usually before the call to the server is made and the handlePaging callback is invoked. Try something like this

```
    var data = [];

    function handlePaging(response) {

      if (response && !response.error) {

        data = data.concat(response.data);

        if (response.paging.next) {
          FB.api(response.paging.next, handlePaging);
        } else {
          console.log(data);
        }

      }

    }

    FB.api("/me/groups", handlePaging);
```

Comment: That's outputting an empty array, repeatedly.  I've ended up just re-planning on how the script works to get around it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that Array.concat returns a new array and the results of data.concat were being thrown away. I fixed my answer.

Comment: Thanks, thats worked, I was expecting concat to be done in place as well